# Enable E-cores in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, cpu

I have a rented server with having Intel 12th Gen Alder Lake Processor. I guess the E-cores are disabled.
When I run  lscpu --all --extended, I get the following output.

[image: output]

I don't see a core with max frequency less than 5900MHZ.
Is there a way to enable the E-cores?
I have Linux 5.15.0-52-generic installed on the server.

Comment: I think you're still waiting for the cutting edge Linux kernel work to determine how this can actually be used (since the E-cores have a different feature set, threads will need to indicate to the scheduler whether or not they can run on these cores).  That's work that's still in early stages as I understand it.

Comment: See [Hybrid scheduling gets more complicated](https://lwn.net/Articles/909611/).

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Comment: Most likely E-cores are disabled outside your system, e.g. in the system BIOS or in your hypervisor. Talk to your hosting provider.